# error in changing typeface in xamarin for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, typeface

I want to change font of my textview and I follow the code given in tutorials and samples. But I am getting error in it.
my code is

```
var txt = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Context.Assets, "fonts/k010.ttf");
        txt.SetTypeface (tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

I am getting error in 2nd line the error says

> The object refrance is required for non static field,method

I want to use kruti dev 10 font in my textview.

Comment: please show more code of class where you are calling Typeface.CreateFromAsset ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Context.Assets, "fonts/k010.ttf");
```

to

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/k010.ttf");
```

Comment: it says native typeface can not be made

Comment: Check your Font file it either currpted or contains TTF in its extension

Answer (score 1):

please change

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/k010.ttf");
```

to

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (this.getAssets(), "fonts/k010.ttf");
```

please refer below link for better solution regarding this.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Graphics/Typefaces.cs

Comment: there is no getassest method in xamarin api for android

Comment: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.FontSample   please refer this, I am sure u will get your solution. please focus on MyEditText.cs from the reference Project.

Comment: Thanks for answering karan but i tried this before posting the question. It's code is in java and i am using c#. it doesn't make my work.